# How to make a Python script linking to another application

Tags: python

I'm learning python script to make an autogame and i don't know how can the script interact with another application
I've heard that using hook technique but I do not know how to do it with python. Can anyone help me with HOOK and making autogame?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [How to run bash commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python) and with bash you can launch any application with all the arguments the application supports at the time of the launch.

Comment: @teestdm bash commands is what actually happens in the background when you interact with a GUI. You can google up some basic commands on how to launch your application for your Operating System. Write those commands using the python library in my answer and you will be good to go